# In SQL, to notice which author is the most popular from readers in my data

Tags: mysql, sql, database

First table

```
BibNum  ItemBarcode ItemType    Collection  CallNumber  CheckoutDateTime
```

Second Table

```
BibNum  Title   Author  ISBN    PublicationYear Publisher   Subjects    ItemType    ItemCollection  FloatingItem    ItemLocation    ReportDate  ItemCount
```

I need to get which author is the most popular from the readers, BibNum means the account number for each reader. I think I can use BibNum, ItemType in the first table and BibNum, Title, Author, ItemType in the second table to use join or something.
Please enlighten me if you have any suggestion and help. If you have any doubts to tables, let me know I will try to clarify to you.

Here is my sample data in each table

First table

```
1842225 10035249209 acbk    namys   MYSTERY ELKINS1999  05/23/2005 03:20:00 PM
1928264 10037335444 jcbk    ncpic   E TABACK    12/14/2005 05:56:00 PM
1982511 10039952527 jcvhs   ncvidnf VHS J796.2 KNOW_YO 2000 08/11/2005 01:52:00 PM
2026467 10040985615 accd    nacd    CD 782.421642 Y71T  10/19/2005 07:47:00 PM
2174698 10047696215 jcbk    ncpic   E KROSOCZ   12/29/2005 03:42:00 PM
```

Second table

```
3011076 A tale of two friends / adapted by Ellie O'Ryan ; illustrated by Tom Caulfield, Frederick Gardner, Megan Petasky, and Allen Tam.    O'Ryan, Ellie   1481425730, 1481425749, 9781481425735, 9781481425742    2014    Simon Spotlight,    Musicians Fiction, Bullfighters Fiction, Best friends Fiction, Friendship Fiction, Adventure and adventurers Fiction    jcbk    ncrdr   Floating    qna 09/01/2017  1
2248846 Naruto. Vol. 1, Uzumaki Naruto / story and art by Masashi Kishimoto ; [English adaptation by Jo Duffy]. Kishimoto, Masashi, 1974-   1569319006  2003, c1999.    Viz,    Ninja Japan Comic books strips etc, Comic books strips etc Japan Translations into English, Graphic novels  acbk    nycomic NA  lcy 09/01/2017  1
3209270 Peace, love & Wi-Fi : a ZITS treasury / by Jerry Scott and Jim Borgman. Scott, Jerry, 1955- 144945867X, 9781449458676   2014    Andrews McMeel Publishing,  Duncan Jeremy Fictitious character Comic books strips etc, Teenagers United States Comic books strips etc, Parent and teenager Comic books strips etc, Families Comic books strips etc, Comic books strips etc, Comics Graphic works, Humorous comics   acbk    nycomic NA  bea 09/01/2017  1
1907265 The Paris pilgrims : a novel / Clancy Carlile.  Carlile, Clancy, 1930-  786706155   c1999.  Carroll & Graf, Hemingway Ernest 1899 1961 Fiction, Biographical fiction, Historical fiction    acbk    cafic   NA  cen 09/01/2017  1
1644616 Erotic by nature : a celebration of life, of love, and of our wonderful bodies / edited by David Steinberg.     094020813X  1991, c1988.    Red Alder Books/Down There Press,   Erotic literature American, American literature 20th century    acbk    canf    NA  cen 09/01/2017  1
```

For this data, second space bar means each values of each column. If you don't get what data is meaning of this sample data, let me know I will try to show clearly.

Drivers

```
| bibnum          | string          | from deserializer |
| title           | string          | from deserializer |
| author          | string          | from deserializer |
| isbn            | string          | from deserializer |
| publicationyear | string          | from deserializer |
| publisher       | string          | from deserializer |
| subjects        | string          | from deserializer |
| itemtype        | string          | from deserializer |
| itemcollection  | string          | from deserializer |
| floatingitem    | string          | from deserializer |
| itemlocation    | string          | from deserializer |
| reportdate      | string          | from deserializer |
| itemcount       | string          | from deserializer
```

timesheet

```
| bibnum          | string          | from deserializer |
| itembarcode     | string          | from deserializer |
| itemtype        | string          | from deserializer |
| itemcollection  | string          | from deserializer |
| callnumber      | string          | from deserializer |
| checkoutdatetime | string          | from deserializer |

0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default> SELECT t2.Author
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .> FROM  timesheet t1
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .> INNER JOIN drivers t2
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .> on t1.BibNum = t2.Bibnum
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .> GROUP BY t2.Author
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .> ORDER BY count(t1.Bibnum) DESC 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .> LIMIT 1;
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 6:15 Invalid table alias or column reference 't1': (possible column names are: author) (state=42000,code=10004)
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default>
```

Comment: can you put sample data and some indication of what you consider the most popular author so based on that we probably can help with your query.

Comment: I will put up samples in each table. Hold on second please and thank you and I guess the result I am expecting would be the count of books readers borrowed and authors based on their books they wrote.